# Do sentences in present perfect tense have multiple possible interpretations?

Tags: present-perfect

As a native Czech speaker I have always been puzzled about the present perfect tense in English, since we don't really have any similar language phenomenon in our language and thus it's very hard to draw any conclusions or parallels in some cases.

While going through some exercises I encountered the following sentence.

> Are you going to the dinner on Saturday? A lot of my other friends *were invited* / *have been invited* and I know they'd love to meet you.

The task is obviously to chose the correct form of the sentence, but the way I think about this, the present perfect tense should be only used when regarding states that started in the past and have continuation into present, but since I have no information whether the invitation process has already ended, how am I supposed to decide this?

Another example that pops into mind is a conversation between two relatives going as follows:

> A: How many times *has* aunt May *been* to London?
>
> B: She *was* in London 3 times.

Now, should A immediately say something like "I'm sorry, what happened?" because B is obviously implying that either London ceased to exist unbeknownst to A or that aunt May may no longer visit London due to her own inability.

Comment: We would use _a lot of my friends have been invited_ because the dinner hasn't yet taken place. You don't need to know whether or not the host has stopped sending out invitations, the point is that invitations have been issued but not yet taken up on. We would only use _were invited_ when speaking of an event that has passed.

Comment: Indeed, the present perfect doesn't require the action to be continuing into the present.  It requires only that the action be perceived as still relevant ("I have passed a number of exams", "I have visited Italy three times", "Jim has eaten his lunch").

Comment: The second exchange is simply unidiomatic. You wouldn't use "was" there; however you might say "she was in London for three years" in response to the question "How long was Aunt May in London?"